# Set default value for RangePicker with form in Ant-Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I have an application that could get the data from the frontend and store it in the state.

For some of the inputs I set the default value using:

```js
  form.setFieldsValue({
    note: text.note,
    gender: text.gender
  });
```

but i also want to set the default value for RangePicker. I have the data that should be in default state:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setText({
      note: "2",
      gender: "demo",
      start: "2020-03-09 13:00", //set as default value for Range Picker
      end: "2020-03-27 13:17" //set as default value for Range Picker
    });
  }, []);
```

How to set default value for Range Picker precisely using `form.setFieldsValue`?
link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-hzgg7

Comment: @keikai, could you take a look , please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302130/save-values-in-array-of-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ant Design [RangePicker API](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker)

The props **value** and **defaultValue** both have a type of:

> [moment, moment]

So set the default value as below would work:

```
Picker: [moment("2020-03-09 13:00"), moment("2020-03-27 13:17")]
```

Full code: (`Picker` having an uppercase first letter, better to change it)

```
useEffect(() => {
  setText({
    note: "2",
    gender: "demo",
    Picker: [moment("2020-03-09 13:00"), moment("2020-03-27 13:17")]
  });
}, []);

form.setFieldsValue({
  note: text.note,
  gender: text.gender,
  Picker: text.Picker
});

<Form.Item name="Picker" label="date"> // the name here is `Picker` from your code
  <RangePicker
    showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    onChange={onChange2}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

[image]